# Refactoring rxjs 5 to rxjs 6 code - retryWhen

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, rxjs

I've had this service code written in rxjs 5 notation:

```
      constructor(private _authService: AuthService) {
    this._ws$ = WebSocketSubject.create<any>({
      url: WS_URL,
      protocol: this._authService.token
    });

    this._ws$.retryWhen(errors => {
        // switchMap to retrieve the source error
        return errors.switchMap(sourceErr => {
            console.log('Retry WS.', sourceErr);
            return Observable.timer(1000).map(() => Observable.of(true));
          }
        );
      }
    ).subscribe(
      msg => {
        if ('channel_name' in msg) {
          console.log('Channel name', msg.channel_name);
          this._channelName = msg.channel_name;
          this._authService.channelName = msg.channel_name;
        }
        this.subject$.next(msg);
        console.log(msg);
      },
      err => {
        console.log(err);
        this.subject$.error(err);
      },
      () => this.subject$.complete()
    );
  }
```

I am trying to refactor it to rxjs 6 valid code and I have got this now:

```
constructor(private _authService: AuthService) {
this._ws$ = WebSocketSubject.create({
  url: WS_URL,
  protocol: this._authService.token
});

retryWhen(() => {
    // switchMap to retrieve the source error
    return switchMap(() => {
        return timer(1000).pipe(map(() => of(true)));
      }
    );
  }
).subscribe(
  msg => {
    if ('channel_name' in msg) {
      this._channelName = msg.channel_name;
      this._authService.channelName = msg.channel_name;
    }
    this.subject$.next(msg);
  },
  err => {
    this.subject$.error(err);
  },
  () => this.subject$.complete()
);
```

But I am getting following error:

```
TS2345: Argument of type '() => OperatorFunction<{}, Observable<boolean>>' is not assignable to parameter of type '(errors: Observable<any>) => Observable<any>'.
    Type 'OperatorFunction<{}, Observable<boolean>>' is not assignable to type 'Observable<any>'.
    Property '_isScalar' is missing in type 'OperatorFunction<{}, Observable<boolean>>'.
```

I cannot figure out what is the best way of using retryWhen function here and how to use WebSocketSubject inside it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An implementation of the above code in Rxjs 6 would look something like the below

```
 this._ws$.pipe(
  retryWhen(errors =>
    errors.pipe(
      tap(val => console.log('Retry WS.', val)),
      delay(1000)
    )
  )).subscribe( msg => {
    if ('channel_name' in msg) {
      this._channelName = msg.channel_name;
      this._authService.channelName = msg.channel_name;
    }
    this.subject$.next(msg);
  },err => {
    this.subject$.error(err);
  },() => this.subject$.complete()
  );
```

For more information on retry when with Rxjs 6 you can refer to here
https://www.learnrxjs.io/operators/error_handling/retrywhen.html

Comment: Thank you, code works well but there is still a warning that delayWhen is deprecated.

Comment: @TomislavBrabec nice catch, updated it to use delay instead of delayWhen.